# Why setInterval() is not working in angular6?

Tags: angular6

When I call setInterval() function it does not work. But if I remove clearInterval() function then it execute. But I want to clear setInterval to stop infinite execution.

```
    this.interval = setInterval( () => {
          console.log('stoptyping');
          if (msg_area.onfocus) {
              console.log('stoptyping');
              const stdata = {
                  chatId: this.chatId,
                  userId: this.common.getUserId()
              };
              this.chatService.iamStopTyping(stdata);
          } else {
              console.log('interval test1');
              clearInterval(this.interval);
              const stdata = {
                  chatId: this.chatId,
                  userId: this.common.getUserId()
              };
              this.chatService.iamStopTyping(stdata);
          }
      }, 2000);
      console.log('interval test2');
      if (this.interval) {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
      }
```

Comment: Why would you clear the interval immediately after starting it?

Comment: There is  condition that if current user defocus the message box the I clear the interval and send the stop typing response.

Comment: With your code it will always cancel the interval.

Comment: So, how can I fix this?

Comment: Well, you should clearinterval only at some condition or an event on defocus of check box as you said.

Comment: Can you tell me after which clearInteval() removing the setInterval() works ?

Comment: But there have a condition if not focus then clear the interval.

Comment: @FahimUddin if user defocus the textarea the clearInterval() is execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console.log('interval test2');
if (this.interval) {
  clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

What is the purpose of this piece of code? It is terminating your setInterval() before happening anything useful, just remove it and it should work.

So you solution would be :

```
this.interval = setInterval( () => {
      console.log('stoptyping');
      if (msg_area.onfocus) {
          console.log('stoptyping');
          const stdata = {
              chatId: this.chatId,
              userId: this.common.getUserId()
          };
          this.chatService.iamStopTyping(stdata);
          return;
      } 
      console.log('interval test1');
      clearInterval(this.interval);
      const stdata = {
          chatId: this.chatId,
          userId: this.common.getUserId()
      };
      this.chatService.iamStopTyping(stdata);
  }, 2000);
```

Comment: @Santu If you think my answer is your solution, please mark my answer as solved.